# php runs terminal app with system()/shell_exec()/exec() but only half of the output shows up

Tags: php, c++, bash, system, shell-exec

so I have a php script:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    //print_r($_GET);
    $command = '../../build/program_name ' . $_GET['arg_id'];
    $command .= ' -test '.$_GET['arg1'].' '.$_GET['arg2'];


    //echo $command . "\n";
    //system('pwd');
    //system('ls -la ../../build');

    //system('../../build/program_name 17 -test 125 1500 2>&1');
    //passthru('../../build/program_name 17 -test 125 1500');
    system('../../build/program_name 17 -test 125 1500');
    //system($command);
    //$data = exec($command);
    //var_dump($data);

    //echo $data;
    //echo "\n";
?>
```

simple version:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    system('../../build/program_name 17 -test 125 1500');
?>
```

The output from this is:

```
argv[0] = ../../build/program_name
argv[1] = 17
argv[2] = -test
argv[3] = 125
argv[4] = 1500
argc = 5 so appears to be test request.
TEST(125, 1500) test requested.
```

If I run the command in the terminal however the output is:

```
argv[0] = ../../build/program_name
argv[1] = 17
argv[2] = -test
argv[3] = 125
argv[4] = 1500
argc = 5 so appears to be test request.
TEST(125, 1500) test requested.
{ "function": "test" , "inputs": [125.000000, 1500.000000], "output": 999.000000}
```

the last bit of output (the important part) isn't showing up when php runs the exact same command... I've printed the working directory and the command just to verify that I'm in fact running the command correctly, the results are consistently the same across exec, shell_exec, and system.... I'm just at a loss for what is happening here...

Edit: additional info about 'program_name' heres an extremely simplified version. its c++:

```
    float arg1;
    float arg2;
    if(argc == 5){
        arg1 = atof(argv[3]);
        arg2 = atof(argv[4]);
    } else {
        cout << "please supply appropriate args" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    #ifdef DEBUG
        cout << "TEST(" << arg1 << ", " << arg2 << ") test requested." << endl;
    #endif

    float output = test(arg1, arg2);

    string jsonOut = "{ ";
    jsonOut.append(
            "\"function\": \"test\" , ").append(
            "\"inputs\": [").append(to_string(arg1)).append(", ").append(to_string(arg2)).append("], ").append(
            "\"output\": ").append(to_string(output)).append("}");
    cout << jsonOut << endl;
    return 0;
```

Comment: I suspect the program prints the last line to `stdout` and everything else to `stderr`. The `system()` function redirects `stdout` to itself, and returns the last line of the output.

Comment: agree with @Barmar. Try `system('../../build/program_name 17 -test 125 1500 2>&1');`

Comment: @AlexBlex Actually, it should be `1>&2`

Comment: no, system captures stdout, and ignores stderr.  The last line comes to console from `program_name`

Comment: adding 1>&2 didn't help I've edited the question to show my code commented out.

Comment: Can you post the code of `program_name`?

Comment: The question is very confusing with all that commented-out code. Which is the actual code that you're running?

Comment: @Barmar unfortunately i can't it's really long, under an NDA, and not that exciting, basically it prints everything via cout with no exceptions.

Comment: I've run the various lines of commented out code but they all produce the same result. but I've left them in there for the benefit of everyone to know what I've already tried.

Comment: Can you post a simplified version of the program that doesn't have any of the proprietary bits?

Comment: @Barmar posted.

Comment: If you change the order of the output in the program, the problem always affects the last line?

Comment: php ingores all new output added after and including the output of jsonOut.(all additional output shows up in the terminal though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is insane, but fixed it. the program 'program_name' was saving a little log file using fprintf(). php would ignore all output from the program after the first call to fprintf()... commenting out fprintf() and recompiling program_name fixed the problem and now php doesn't bail in the middle, apparently php is incompatible to calls to fprintf() on OS X???

Answer (score 1):

Use [`passthru()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) instead of `system()`. The difference is that `passthru()` passes the command's output through to PHP's output, while `system()` captures the output and returns the last line.

The other output you're seeing is presumably written to `stderr`, which `system()` doesn't capture.

Comment: No good, I'll edit the question with my attempts commented out.